# MySQL detect capitalization?

Tags: mysql

I want to do a query via phpmyadmin in which I can find any entries for Lastname that are not capitalized. Can I do that purely with sql?

If not: is there an easy way with php, or do I have to write code starting with substring()? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT lastname
FROM tbl
WHERE CONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTRING( lastname, 1, 1 ) ) ,
              LOWER( SUBSTRING( lastname FROM 2 ) ) ) != lastname Collate latin1_german2_cs;
```

The left side creates a proper-cased lastname, and compares it against the column case sensitively (using _cs collation)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. For some reason, my installation says: "#1273 - Unknown collation: 'latin1_german2_cs' ".  (Although I do have the case insensitive latin1_german2 collation.) So I used NOT LIKE BINARY and that works.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html), you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
  WHERE your_field COLLATE <your_collation> REGEXP '[[:lower:]]+';
-- <your_collation> being a case sensitive collation,
-- such as latin1_general_cs, or utf8_bin, depending on your_table collation
```

Comment: Thanks, I've saved the regexp in case I need that in future. And latin1_general_cs works like a charm!

Comment: And latin1_general_cs works like a charm and lets me use Richard's code. Thanks, I learned a lot today from you both!